# javascript three digits counter how to do?

Tags: javascript

I need to count numbers from 1 - 999 using three digits output.

Here is what i need:

```
001
002
003
004
005
006
007 
008
009
010
011
  .
  .
  .
099
100
  .
  .
  .
999
```

Is this possible using javascript or jQuery? Many Thanks.

Comment: it's just string formatting. if <10, add 2 zeroes, if < 99, add one zero

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, just print the numbers from 1-999 with padded zeroes at the beginning when needed.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 999; i++) {
   console.log(("00" + i).slice(-3));
}
```

You can see this [in action on this jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2nQ4U/).

Comment: woow..that's was quick..this is what i need...i was searching for javascript command but i now learn that is slice. Many Thanks.